# Is it good practice to force unwrap optional values retrieved from UserDefaults instead of safely unwrapping with guard/if let?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

A lot of tutorials online seem to favour using `if-let` or `guard-let` statements to retrieve optional values from UserDefaults. Does this make any sense? I read that Apple intends for us to immediately give default values for UserDefaults.

Using guard statements to safely unwrap these values results in more code and seems redundant if your app initializes these values right away. Are there any drawbacks of force unwrapping values from UserDefaults?

Answer (score 5):

Returning `nil` is a perfectly reasonable thing for UserDefaults to do when the key you supply is not defined. Moreover, the value that comes back from UserDefaults when you say `object(forKey:)` has no definite type — starting in Xcode 8 seed 6, it is an Any. The use of `if/guard let` is a way to ask, in a single expression, whether this value is non-`nil` and, if so, whether it can be cast down to the type you expect, without any danger of crashing. Thus this is *great* way of proceeding. It is *not* force-unwrapping or force-casting. It is safe unwrapping and safe casting. If it fails, the condition fails, and no harm done.

Force-unwrapping or force-casting would involve the use of the exclamation mark (`!`). Of course you are perfectly free to force-unwrap and force-cast if you are absolutely 100% sure of your ground. But bear in mind that the primary meaning of the exclamation mark is "Please crash me!" You cannot be surprised when your assumptions turn out to be wrong and Swift does just what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different cases to handle `NSUserDefaults`:

- If you **don't register** a default value for a key in `NSUserDefaults` the returned value can be `nil` and you must not forced unwrap the value as *matt* described in his answer.
- However if you **do register** a default value for a key in `NSUserDefaults` – as Apple recommends in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) – you can safely unwrap the value because the framework returns reliably the default value in case the "physical" key in the property list file is missing.

Comment: That is true for `objectForKey`, but some "specialized" methods like `stringForKey` can return `nil` even if a default values was registered. That would happen if a value for the key exists,  but the type does not match, e.g. if the value is set to an array.

Comment: @MartinR Right but that is a coding fault caused by the developer.